# Grab/Fetch Facebook comments through query.using Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I was trying to fetch facebook comments then put it into my own website so then I could reply it through my website. After doing some research, I found it Graph API could be the solution to my problem. Below is the code

```
<?php
         $group_id ="14********_1**********99";
         $access_token="accesstoken";

         $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/" . $group_id . 
         "/comments?
         fields=message,from{name,id}&access_token=".$access_token;


             $json= file_get_contents($url);
             $data = json_decode($json);

            foreach ($data->comments->data as $key) {
            if(isset($key->message))
            {
               echo $key->message;

               echo "<br>";     
             }
        }

     ?>
```

How do I fetch comments from Facebook through the URL above? Sorry I'm still new to programming.

Comment: never show credentials

Comment: can you help my problem? @Archish